# What exactly is the Bayesian model average probability of the following?

Tags: bayesian, posterior, bayesian-network, model-averaging

I am struggling to understand Bayesian Model Averaging. Suppose I have got a simple Bayesian network, $X\to Y$ where X and Y are binary variables and I have got 2 models:

- Model 1 (simple): 
  $$P(Y=1\vert X=1)=\theta \quad\text{and}\quad P(Y=1\vert X=0)=\theta$$
- Model 2 (complex): 
  $$
  P(Y=1\vert X=1)=\theta_1\quad\text{and}\quad P(Y=1\vert X=0)=\theta_2$$

If I assume the parameters prior to be Beta distributed and hence the posterior to be Beta distributed as well. What would be the averaged posterior of the 2 models? I am mainly confused as there are 1 parameter in model 1 and 2 parameters in model 2, I'm not sure what the posterior average would look like. Thanks!

P.S. I understand how to derive posterior model weight $P(M_1\vert D)$ and $P(M_2\vert D)$

Comment: I'm not an expert on BMA but I don't think the technique is designed to be applied to model posteriors wholesale. Alternatively, maybe you could reparameterize the second model so that $\theta_1 = \theta$ and $\theta_2 = \theta + \alpha$. At least then $\theta$ kind of has a consistent interpretation across models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to write the models in a consistent way -- so the parameters of interest in the larger model are present in the smaller model (but may be restricted in some way -- you'd just ignore the restriction when averaging).

In your smaller model, you simply have $\theta_1=\theta$ and $\theta_2=\theta$.

There's no obvious difficulty in averaging those $(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ values with the values from the model where they differ.

The effect of averaging the full model with the reduced model would be to "shrink" estimates (well, at least ones like say posterior means) toward the common estimate in the smaller model. More fully, the model-averaged posterior distribution would be a mixture of the case where you have separate $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ and the case where $\theta_1=\theta_2$.

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Glen_b. But do you mean BMA cannot be applied when the models are non-nested?

Comment: Not at all; you asked about a case where they were, so it's not surprising that my answer talked about that situation. However, if they're not all at least submodels of some larger model, you wouldn't have common parameters to apply that averaging to. (You could still average predictions, of course.)